# R: añadir leyenda proporcional a un gráfico de redes

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un análisis de redes y me gustaría añadir la leyenda al gráfico.
Me gustaría añadirlo pero el tamaño de la leyenda no se ajusta al del gráfico.

estos son los dataframes:

```
      DF_H_nodes <- data.frame(
        nodes = c("Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez", "Corticosteroides sistemicos", "Antitromboticos", "Antibacterianos uso sistemico", "Psicolepticos", "Sin clasificar", "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares", "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales", "Diureticos", "Sustit plasma y sol para infusion", "Analgesicos", "Antidiabeticos", "Betabloqueantes adrenergicos", "Bloqueadores de canales de calcio", "Psicoanalepticos", "Antiepilepticos", "Antigripales y antitusivos", "Antivirales uso sistemico", "Laxantes", "Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos", "Agentes que actúan sobre el sistema renina angiotensina"),
        group = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )



        data.frame(
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          from = c("Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez","Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos","Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Antitromboticos","Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos","Antitromboticos","Psicolepticos",
                   "Psicolepticos","Sin clasificar","Sin clasificar",
                   "Sin clasificar","Sin clasificar",
                   "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares",
                   "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares","Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares",
                   "Psicolepticos","Psicolepticos","Psicolepticos",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares","Sin clasificar",
                   "Antibacterianos uso sistemico","Diureticos","Diureticos",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales","Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares","Sin clasificar",
                   "Sustit plasma y sol para infusion",
                   "Sustit plasma y sol para infusion","Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos","Diureticos",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez","Analgesicos","Antidiabeticos",
                   "Antitromboticos","Betabloqueantes adrenergicos",
                   "Betabloqueantes adrenergicos",
                   "Bloqueadores de canales de calcio","Bloqueadores de canales de calcio",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos","Diureticos",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez","Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares",
                   "Psicoanalepticos","Psicoanalepticos",
                   "Psicoanalepticos","Psicolepticos","Psicolepticos","Sin clasificar",
                   "Sin clasificar","Sin clasificar",
                   "Sustit plasma y sol para infusion","Sustit plasma y sol para infusion",
                   "Sustit plasma y sol para infusion",
                   "Sustit plasma y sol para infusion","Antidiabeticos","Antidiabeticos",
                   "Antiepilepticos","Antigripales y antitusivos",
                   "Antigripales y antitusivos","Antitromboticos","Antitromboticos",
                   "Antitromboticos","Antivirales uso sistemico",
                   "Betabloqueantes adrenergicos","Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos","Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos","Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Diureticos","Diureticos",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez","Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez","Laxantes",
                   "Laxantes","Laxantes","Laxantes",
                   "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares",
                   "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares",
                   "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares","Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares",
                   "Psicoanalepticos","Psicoanalepticos","Psicolepticos",
                   "Psicolepticos","Sin clasificar","Sin clasificar",
                   "Sin clasificar","Sustit plasma y sol para infusion"),
            to = c("Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Antibacterianos uso sistemico","Antitromboticos","Analgesicos",
                   "Antitromboticos","Antibacterianos uso sistemico","Analgesicos",
                   "Analgesicos","Analgesicos","Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Antibacterianos uso sistemico","Antitromboticos",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez","Analgesicos","Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez","Analgesicos",
                   "Antibacterianos uso sistemico","Antitromboticos",
                   "Analgesicos",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales","Corticosteroides sistemicos","Analgesicos",
                   "Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos",
                   "Antitromboticos","Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Antibacterianos uso sistemico","Antitromboticos",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos","Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos",
                   "Diureticos","Antitromboticos","Psicolepticos","Analgesicos",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos",
                   "Betabloqueantes adrenergicos","Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Betabloqueantes adrenergicos","Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos",
                   "Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos","Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Antitromboticos","Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Antitromboticos","Bloqueadores de canales de calcio",
                   "Analgesicos","Diureticos","Antidiabeticos",
                   "Bloqueadores de canales de calcio",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales","Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales",
                   "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares","Bloqueadores de canales de calcio",
                   "Diureticos",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales","Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Antitromboticos","Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Farmacos para alteraciones funcionales gastrointestinales",
                   "Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos","Analgesicos",
                   "Antibacterianos uso sistemico","Analgesicos",
                   "Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Agentes que actúan sobre el sistema renina angiotensina","Antidiabeticos","Antigripales y antitusivos",
                   "Antitromboticos","Analgesicos",
                   "Agentes que actúan sobre el sistema renina angiotensina","Antidiabeticos",
                   "Antiepilepticos","Antigripales y antitusivos",
                   "Antivirales uso sistemico",
                   "Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos","Betabloqueantes adrenergicos",
                   "Agentes que actúan sobre el sistema renina angiotensina","Antiepilepticos",
                   "Antigripales y antitusivos",
                   "Antivirales uso sistemico","Analgesicos","Antibacterianos uso sistemico",
                   "Corticosteroides sistemicos",
                   "Farmacos para enf  Relacionadas con acidez","Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos",
                   "Betabloqueantes adrenergicos","Diureticos","Laxantes",
                   "Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos",
                   "Antitromboticos","Antivirales uso sistemico","Diureticos",
                   "Agentes que reducen los lípidos séricos","Antidiabeticos",
                   "Preparados para enf  Obstructivas pulmonares",
                   "Sin clasificar"),
        weight = c(16L,16L,15L,15L,15L,15L,
                   14L,13L,12L,11L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,9L,9L,
                   9L,9L,9L,9L,8L,8L,8L,8L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,
                   7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,6L,6L,6L,6L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,
                   5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,
                   5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,
                   4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,
                   4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L),
         group = c(2L,2L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,1L,
                   1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
                   2L,2L,2L,2L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
                   2L,2L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,1L,2L,2L,2L,1L,1L,1L,2L,
                   2L,2L,2L,2L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
                   2L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,1L,1L,
                   1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,
                   2L,2L,2L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L)
        )
```

y este es el código utilizado:

```
     hero_net1<-graph_from_data_frame(d=DF_H_edges,
                                      vertices = DF_H_nodes,
                                      directed = F)


     type_color<-c("#4283c0","#469043","#FF0000")

     DF_H_edges %>% mutate(color=case_when(group==1 ~ type_color[1],
                                           group==2 ~ type_color[2],
                                           group==3 ~ type_color[3],
                                           TRUE ~ as.character(NA)))->DF_H_edges


     DF_H_nodes %>% mutate(color=case_when(group==1 ~ type_color[1],
                                           group==2 ~ type_color[2],
                                           group==3 ~ type_color[3],
                                           TRUE ~ as.character(NA)))->DF_H_nodes



     BD_pivot_M_sums %>% 
       mutate(percent = (size/sum(BD_pivot_M_sums$size))*100)->BD_pivot_M_sums
     DF_H_nodes %>% 
       left_join(BD_pivot_M_sums,by = "nodes") ->DF_H_nodes


    par(bg = "#414143",
        # Change the colors
        col.main="grey", col.sub="lightgrey",
        # Titles in italic and bold
        font.main=2, font.sub=4,
        # Change font size
        cex.main=1.5, cex.sub=1.2)

    plot(hero_net1, 
         layout = layout_with_kk, 
         edge.color="black",
         edge.width=E(hero_net1)$weight/2.5, 
         vertex.color = DF_H_nodes$color[V(hero_net1)],
         # vertex.label 
         edge.curved =0.1, 
         vertex.size = DF_H_nodes$percent*2,
         vertex.label.color = "white", 
         vertex.label.cex =0.8,
         vertex.label.dist = 1.2,
         vertex.label.font=1,
         vertex.frame.color = "black",
         main = "Use of COVID inpatient treatments for LONG-COVID patients",
         family="Arial Black",
         vertex.label.degree = pi/2,
         asp = 1,
         mark.border = NA,
         mark.expand = NA)


    legend("topright",
           legend=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
           pch=c(19),
           col=c("#469043"),
           title="Prevalence",
           adj = 1,
           pt.cex=c(1,
                    5,
                    10,
                    15,
                    20),

           cex=1)
```

y este es el plot resultante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el tamaño de los puntos se ajuste al del plot?
también me gustaría hace uno con lineas y que se ajuste con el de las lineas del plot ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con ggplot2 no he sabido responderlo pero hay otra función que es ggraph que si permite poner la leyenda proporcional acorde con el gráfico:

```
library(ggraph)
V(hero_net1)$degree <- degree(hero_net1)
ggraph(hero_net1, 'igraph', algorithm = 'kk') + 
  geom_edge_link(aes(width = weight,
                     # alpha = weight
                     ), edge_alpha = 0.1,colour = "black") + 
  geom_node_point(aes(size = degree, 
                      # alpha = degree
                      ), colour = 'forestgreen') + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), color = 'white', 
                 size = 3, repel=TRUE) + 
  ggforce::theme_no_axes() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray")) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 15))+
  labs(edge_width = "Co-administration")
```